# How can I control access of mounted files to other accounts?

Tags: mount, permissions, truecrypt

When I mount files via cryptkeeper and truecrypt they show up on the desktop of admin account but also guest and family accounts.

How can I stop mounted files and hard drives to appear and being accessed from family and guest accounts?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use UNIX-style permissions to restrict what accounts can read the file.  If you go to the folders in Nautilus, right click, select Properties, and go to the Permissions tab.  Remove any permissions other than Owner and click "Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files".  Then only the owner (should be you, if you mounted the filesystems) can read the files.